# How to use activity from some another thread "CalledFromWrongThreadException"

Tags: android, user-interface, text-to-speech

I use MediaPlayer TextToSpeech classes. I need to catch the moment when speaking is ended. I use this code:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            speechRecognizer.startListenig();
            //binding.play.performClick();
        }
    });

    TTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            speechRecognizer.startListenig();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) { }
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) { }
    });
```

The both listeners start this method:

```
public void startListenig(){
    binding.progressSound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    binding.progressSound.setIndeterminate(true);
    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);

}
```

The listener of Media Player works fine.
The listener of Text To Speech throws exception:

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I tried to google this, but I don't understand the source of my trouble, why in case with mediaplayer it is worked and why TTS throws exceptions.

Please give me a hint how to solve this.

Comment: As a personal advice your MediaPlayer class should not know anything about activity. You can pass a listener and run it when start listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform any operation on view, is must be main thread, if you are in other thread than you can not perform operation in that thread.

use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```

method for activity, for fragment or adapter use `context.runOnUiThread()`

if runOnUiThread() not working use,

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // This is your code  
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it make my code work, but it still sort of magic for me. Will read about "Handler" to figure out). Must i add this to MediaPlayer?

Comment: can't figure out this " Must i add this to MediaPlayer?", please explain

Comment: I have two listeners one for MediaPlayer this one works fine. And second for TextToSpeech this one was not working before your help. See the code in the post
Mast i add Handler to MediaPlayer listener?
And why did one work when another did not?
Anyway thanks for help!